# dex lab invisibile token in swap

Tags: spl-token, dex, liquiditypool

I'm trying to exchange my token on dex lab but I can't do it, because it's not visible in the area "buy my token".

You can look here: https://www.dexlab.space/token/9bnKvEK2ymzbrtKGeCSbDtn7Dr1afCQoTTH1y4fL5seK